Display toast message after sign in auth js
I implemented sign-in with Google provider using Next.js 14 and Auth.js, and everything works fine. However, how can I add a toast message after redirecting to the homepage, indicating 'You are successfully authenticated'? Additionally, how can I show a toast message after sign-out, also redirecting to the home?

You can simply use the Toast component inside the shadcn-ui library with the useRouter like this :


"use client";

import { useToast } from "@/hooks/use-toast";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import React from "react";

const AuthDemo = () => {
  const { toast } = useToast();
  const router = useRouter();
  
  const handleSignIn = () => {
    // Simulating the sign-in process
    setTimeout(() => {
      router.push("/random-page");
      toast({
        title: "Signed in successfully",
        description: "Welcome back!",
      });
    }, 1000);
  };

  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col items-center justify-center min-h-screen bg-gray-100">
      <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold mb-4">Auth Demo</h1>

      <button
        onClick={handleSignIn}
        className="bg-green-500 hover:bg-green-600 text-white"
      >
        Sign In
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AuthDemo;



You can use useRouter from next/navigation to redirect user and use Toast component to show toast messages as you like. By the way dont forget to add Toaster component into your top level, for me i just added it into layout.tsx :


//import { Toaster } from "@/components/ui/toaster"; imported from here

return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body
        className={`${geistSans.variable} ${geistMono.variable} antialiased`}
      >
        {children}
        <Toaster />
      </body>
    </html>
  );



